# Rails App for Support Team With Two Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I've looked at some answers on SO and looked up some documentation but most of what I've found is geared towards querying multiple databases with similar data (i.e. replicated dbs or different clients...)

I have a very specific thing I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a support team that needs to monitor the results of some queries against a SQL Server db (for example, if there are > than three rows panic!). Unfortunately I'm not going to be able to use the same server for authentication (which they want) and was thinking of just using sqlite. Anyone ever implemented something similar with any success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The establish_connection method is what you may want here: it lets you override non-default database connection parameters for a particular model. Look up establish_connection at api.rubyonrails.org and that should give you the full documentation for that.